# lvalue ref dereference

Tags: c++

Lets assume the following code compiles:

```
int main()
{
    A* p = new B();     // 1
    C& c = p->method(); // 2
    *c = *p;            // 3
    c = *p;             // 4
}
```

given there is **not** a single `operator=` that expects the class `A`,`B`, `C` and **not** a single casting operator to any of those to any of those.

Is it possible that `B` inherits from `A` inherits from `C`?
And how is it possible that both line 3 and line 4 will compile?

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: References can't be dereferenced (unless they reference a pointer variable), or the referenced object have an overloaded dereference (unary `*`) operator. So `*c` could be invalid.

Comment: this compiles and run :
```class A;
class C{
    public:
    C operator=(const A& a){}
    C operator *(){}
};
class A{
    public:
    C& method(){
    }
};
class B: public A{};




int main()
{
    A* p = new B();     // 1
    C& c = p->method(); // 2
    *c = *p;            // 3
    c = *p;             // 4
}
```
but this is funky code

Comment: sorry for the formatting the question was closed

Comment: just tried with more inheritance and it seems to not need operator= at all
```class A;
class C{
    public:
    C operator *(){}
};
class A: public C{
    public:
    C& method(){
    }
};
class B: public A{};




int main()
{
    A* p = new B();     // 1
    C& c = p->method(); // 2
    *c = *p;            // 3
    c = *p;             // 4
}
```

Comment: If you restrict the limitation to `operator=` to user-defined operators, it's possible, but if we interpret this as "You need to delete all implicitly defined assignment operators for the classes", (4) is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This line

`*c = *p`

could never compile without overloading the `*`operator for `C`. References, while having a lot of similarities to pointers, are not pointers. They are not memory addresses and thus cannot be dereferenced. Instead, they act as pointers that are automatically dereferenced whenever used. Furthermore, references can't be reassigned to point to different objects so although the code would compile if you changed it to `c = *p`, it wouldn't work as intended. `c` would still be pointing to the object that `method` returned.

The relations you described between `A`, `B` and `C` could be the case if you made `c` a pointer to `C` instead of a reference, as well as remove the line 4. The code would then look like this:

```
int main()
{
    A* p = new B(); // works because B inherits from A
    C* c = p->method(); // works because is "method" is a member function
                        // of A and returns a pointer to an instance of C
    c* = *p;            // works because A inherits from C
}
```

Comment: "could never compile.": That is wrong. You can simply overload `operator*` and make OP's code valid under their restrictions (no matter how strict you interpret them).

Comment: @user17732522 Correct. I guess it's always a bad idea to use such definite language when discussing programming.